# How to find the call to fork in my python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, fork, mpi, openmpi

Some module in my python program is calling fork(), and my mpi environment is unhappy with this:

> ---
>
> A process has executed an operation involving a call to the "fork()"
>   system call to create a child process.  Open MPI is currently
>   operating in a condition that could result in memory corruption or
>   other system errors; your job may hang, crash, or produce silent data
>   corruption.  The use of fork() (or system() or other calls that create
>   child processes) is strongly discouraged.
>
> The process that invoked fork was:
>
> Local host:
>
> If you are *absolutely sure* that your application will successfully
>   and correctly survive a call to fork(), you may disable this warning
>   by setting the mpi_warn_on_fork MCA parameter to 0.
>
> ---

The program still runs but the output is garbage.

I'm not sure the if the call to fork is through `os.system`, is that the only way python will ever call fork? I didn't write many of these modules myself, is there some tool I can use to figure out what line is generating that warning?