# Received warning about fork incompatible with MPI. In what circumstances can I ignore it?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork, openmpi, mpi4py

I am using python2.7 multiprocessing together with mpi4py for my calculation and I received warning on fork being used and is not supported by MPI. However my code doesn't crash and the result looks reasonable. Can I ignore the warning?

I am running a MCMC calculation which is embarrassingly parallel and communication between each node is not needed except when they return their result to the root node. Within each node, I use multiprocessing module to spawn even more processes to speed up the calculation.

Everything seems fine except I received a warning from MPI about "The use of fork() is strongly discouraged". Am I correct in thinking that multiprocessing module uses fork?

At the end my script did not crash and the result looks reasonable. However I don't know if the script is reliable. Therefore I would like to ask:

1. Under what circumstances will fork causes problems?
2. Can I ignore the warning if I guarantee that MPI communication will not be used in the forked processes?
3. If I receive my result without crashing, could the result be wrong? Is it the type of error like uninitialized variables in other languages that silently gives you wrong results even without crashing?
4. If I really cannot ignore this warning, what options do I have to have my script fixed?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: A slightly different question on the same issue has been asked before : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923899/how-to-find-the-call-to-fork-in-my-python-program

It does not have an answer nor an update on the problem being solved though.